# How do I install Plasma 5.19 on a raspberry pi while keeping Raspbian?

Tags: packages

I'm trying to do some develepment on kde, and for that I need the latest version. I can't upgrade to another OS. <s>I've tried adding new deb sources and it just dumps a whole lot of errors to the console.</s> I did what was in https://www.preining.info/blog/2020/07/kde-plasma-status-update-2020-07-04/ for Debian Unstable, thinking it was close enough to Raspbian. I added the key he provided and no longer get authentication errors. I'm getting '...74 not upgraded' from sudo apt-get upgrade. I tried `sudo apt-get --with-new-pkgs upgrade` from https://askubuntu.com/questions/601/the-following-packages-have-been-kept-back-why-and-how-do-i-solve-it but it doesn't do anything aside from attempting a normal upgrade. I don't want to do `sudo apt-get install <list of packages kept back>` because that marks them all as manually installed. They said that `sudo apt-get dist-upgrade` can remove things and not to blindly do it.

Comment: `I've tried adding new deb sources` which ones? `it just dumps a whole lot of errors to the console` what errors?

Comment: as of 10 days ago "Plasma 5.19 is on its way to SID" - that's Debian SID (Raspberry Pi OS is Debian derived) - but SID is the unstable dist of Debian, and the Raspberry Pi repos don't include the unstable dist ... so what sources did you try?

Comment: @JaromandaX I updated my question.